# ArcPy nested loop problem

Tags: arcpy, loop

I have a question connected with ArcPy. I was trying to make a nested loop with 2 cursors  - 1st with 2 elements and 2nd with 5 elements. The statement should return 10 connections, e.g. 1-1, 1-2, ... 2-5. 
Here is part of my code:

```
import arcpy
import os.path

folder = "Z:\WOLGA"    
na="na"    
baza = "testy.mdb"    
dataset = "network_analyst"    
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(folder, na, baza, dataset)    
shapePocz = os.path.join(folder, na, baza, dataset, "dom")

listaPktPocz = arcpy.SearchCursor(shapePocz, "", "", "", "")    
shapeKonc = os.path.join(folder, na, baza, dataset, "punkty_docelowe")    
listaPktKonc = arcpy.SearchCursor(shapeKonc, "", "", "", "")    
shapeKoncName = arcpy.Describe(shapeKonc).shapeFieldName    
shapePoczName = arcpy.Describe(shapePocz).shapeFieldName

for pktPocz in listaPktPocz:
    for pktKonc in listaPktKonc:
        print str(pktPocz.numer) + " - " + str(pktKonc.numer)
```

For now I got such connections as: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5 only. The outer loop is not being executed properly.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  Knowing this detail is often important because ArcPy 10.1 had a number of significant features added to it, and it is useful to know what we have to work with.  Just edit it into your original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is definitely the old-type cursor. It often makes some problems with nested loops. I recommend you to use da.SearchCursor. The code should look like this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapePocz, ["numer"]) as searchCursOuter:
    for pktPocz in searchCursOuter:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapeKonc, ["numer"]) as searchCursInner:
            for pktKonc in searchCursInner:
                print str(pktPocz[0]) + " - " + str(pktKonc[0])
```

I bet it works.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be that the cursors aren't being properly closed/deleted.  Whenever possible you should use the new Data Access cursors: arcpy.da.SearchCursor, arcpy.da.UpdateCursor, and arcpy.da.InsertCursor.  You can use a 'with' block, which will automatically close and cleanup your cursors for you:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(listaPktPocz, list_fields=[fieldNameOuter]) as searchCursOuter:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(listaPktKonc, list_fields=[fieldNameInner]) as searchCursInner:
        for pktPocz in searchCursOuter:
            for pktKonc in searchCursInner:
                print str(pktPocz[0]) + " - " + str(pktKonc[0])
```

See the following links:

[Accessing data using cursors (pay attention to the arcpy.da cursors)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)

[Search Cursor (arcpy.da)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000)

Comment: Much better to use `with` statements. However, they don't work with "normal" cursors and the data access module is only available @ 10.1 and above. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the old style cursor which is not compatible with `with` statements, you need to call a `reset()` on your inner loop SearchCursor inside the outer loop. Since the inner loop SearchCursor has already been iterated, you get nothing on your second pass through the inner loop.

```
for pktPocz in listaPktPocz:
    for pktKonc in listaPktKonc:
        print str(pktPocz.numer) + " - " + str(pktKonc.numer)
    listaPktKonc.reset()
```